# Relational Algebra Rename Operation

Tags: relational-algebra

I have this relational algebra query:

%x(code)({('PX5'),('PX6')})

Can you explain to me what this query means?

I know that % is rename operation, x is new name of table, but I dont know, what is in () brackets behind '(code)'. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{('PX5'),('PX6')}` looks like a relation. But I also don't understand your term. A rename is defined as ρ<sub>a/b</sub>(R).

So the best what I could think of your term would be something like ρ<sub>x/code</sub>({('PX5'),('PX6')}), which means:

```
Rename the attribute 'code' into 'x' of the relation {('PX5'),('PX6')}.
```